# Creating CfnCertificate using typescript for AWS IoT core, ERROR : "Invalid request provided"

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-iot

Error :

```
Failed resources:
IotCoreStack | 1:46:26 a.m. | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::IoT::Certificate | MyCfnCertificate1 Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: For certificate mode Default, one of the following combinations must be specified exactly: [CertificatePem and CACertificatePem] OR [CertificateSigningRequest]" (RequestToken: dc01e655-f0ba-5593-8983-f16973de7236, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

 ❌  IotCoreStack failed: Error: The stack named IotCoreStack failed to deploy: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: For certificate mode Default, one of the following combinations must be specified exactly: [CertificatePem and CACertificatePem] OR [CertificateSigningRequest]" (RequestToken: dc01e655-f0ba-5593-8983-f16973de7236, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
    at prepareAndExecuteChangeSet (C:\Users\makad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\api\deploy-stack.ts:386:13)     
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at CdkToolkit.deploy (C:\Users\makad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\cdk-toolkit.ts:219:24)
    at initCommandLine (C:\Users\makad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\cli.ts:347:12)

The stack named IotCoreStack failed to deploy: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: For certificate mode Default, one of the following combinations must be specified exactly: [CertificatePem and CACertificatePem] OR [CertificateSigningRequest]" (RequestToken: dc01e655-f0ba-5593-8983-f16973de7236, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

Code :

```
export class IotCoreStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const cfnCertificate = new iot.CfnCertificate(this, 'MyCfnCertificate1', {
      status: 'ACTIVE',
    });

  }
}
```

IotCoreStack | 1/5 | 1:46:26 a.m. | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::IoT::Certificate | MyCfnCertificate1 Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: For certificate mode Default, one of the following combinations must be specified exactly: [CertificatePem and CACertificatePem] OR [CertificateSigningRequest]" (RequestToken: dc01e655-f0ba-5593-8983-f16973de7236, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

```
// the properties below are optional
  caCertificatePem: 'caCertificatePem',
  certificateMode: 'certificateMode',
  certificatePem: 'certificatePem',
  certificateSigningRequest: 'certificateSigningRequest',
```

What type of value we can put here for sample certificate creation in AWS IoT core?

Answer (score 0):

As your error says, you need to specify your certificate in one of chosen way, it could not be created out of nowhere. In fact, it's missing in CDK docs, but there are described ways how to specify such certificate:

```
Certificate resources
You can specify certificates in one of the following ways:

A certificate signing request (CSR).

A certificate ID of an existing device certificate. (Only certificate IDs can be used with a fleet provisioning template.)

A device certificate created with a CA certificate registered with AWS IoT. If you have more than one CA certificate registered with the same subject field, you must also pass in the CA certificate used to sign the device certificate.
```

source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/provision-template.html